# Best way to merge two Django projects' user tables?

Tags: mysql, django

I've got two Django projects on the same server.  The first launched several months ago, and has since collected hundreds of user accounts.  The second project is launching in a few days, and we'd like the second project to allow users of the first app to authenticate using the same credentials.

At first, I was going to simply dump the user table from the first project into the second project, but this would not allow for a synchronous solution (user creates account on project B, does not then have access to project A).

Does Django have some way of natively switching database names (since they're on the same server) for user authentication, and then back to the original database when finished with authentication?

If not, what do you think would be the best solution for my problem?  Also - we're using MySQL.

Comment: Hrm. So the options below are "NO", "MAYBE", and "WAIT". Not reassuring.

Comment: Multiple database support is now available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wait awhile, eventually Django will get multiple database support.

But as of right now, I think the best solution to your problem would be to synchronize the two database's user tables after changes to either are made.  You can use the signals support to handle this:

```
from django.db import models

def user_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    ... run script to synchronize tables ...
models.signals.post_save.connect(user_post_save, sender=User)
```

You won't be able to use the ORM... but dumping the source table, then dropping the destination and importing into it would be relatively painless.  This could definitely cause timing problems, but transactions would mostly solve that.  If the two sites stepping on each other is a concern, I might look into setting up a write lock on the User table during the update, and set up some kind of a spin-wait cycle on the User model's save() method (or the pre_save signal) to check for a lock before completing the save.  This would guarantee that the post_save signal won't get sent during a synchronization.

Comment: Thanks - this looks like the best solution for now.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably get me shot; *but* you could create the user table of the new project simply as a view of the first project:

```
DROP TABLE proj2.users;
CREATE VIEW proj2.users AS SELECT * FROM proj1.users;
```

Comment: Why is that?? If the table has an auto_increment, that ought to be saved in the proj1 table, thus no collisions

Comment: This would work for reads, but obviously not writes. Ideally, you'd also need to monkey-patch the Users model to mark it as unmanaged in proj2, so Django won't fight with the view. Overall, this will be more trouble then it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Django currently does not have support for multiple databases (there is a [wikipage](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleDatabaseSupport) about that subject).

Another approach would be to write a custom [user authentication](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#other-authentication-sources) module for the second website that will do SQL calls to the first websites database to provide the login. When a user from the first site logins into the second Django will create a user in the second site. But this could have some issues with change full name and email addresses, so it could only really be used to have username and password. Also your users will have to register on the first site to access the second so you would need more customize registration to register on the first.

Comment: I'm sure it'd be possible to convince django.auth to use Database A with some hacking, but then Database B won't be able to use the ORM to provide foreign keys to DB A's user table (a pretty common requirement).

Answer (score 0):

You can usee multidb application to work with many db as you like

http://github.com/kron4eg/multidb-django/tree/master